# two adafruit neopixel loops

Tags: arduino-nano, neopixel

i'm making a device that's kind of based on Russian roulette.

I have 5 LED's  that are normally  white, and when you press the button one of the LED's is marked red.

After some tinkering I figured out how to do this with  the help of adafruit neopixel, but i also want to have a RGB strip with a rainbow effect running on the same arduino at the same time (or only just before the button is pressed).

The problem is that it interferes with the activation and running of my  Russian roulette.
I know you can't run two loops at a time, but is there some kind of way to solve this?

I will put my code below, thanks in advance!

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

const int buttonPin = 2;

int buttonState = 0;

#define LED_PIN  6

#define LED_COUNT 5

#define LED_PIN2  7

#define LED_COUNT2 60


Adafruit_NeoPixel strip(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip2(LED_COUNT2, LED_PIN2, NEO_RGBW + NEO_KHZ800);

uint32_t wit = strip.Color(255, 255, 255);
uint32_t wit2 = strip2.Color(255, 255, 255);

void setup() {
   
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  strip.begin();           
  strip.show();            
  strip.setBrightness(255); 
  strip2.begin();           
  strip2.show();            
  strip2.setBrightness(255); 
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  
}

void loop() {
    rainbow(10); 
    shotknop();
}

void shotknop (){
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
    strip.fill(wit, 0, LED_COUNT);
    strip.show();
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
    theaterChase(strip.Color(255, 255, 255), 150);
    shot(strip.Color(0, 255, 0), 100, 5000, 0);
    }
    else{
      }
}


void shot (uint32_t color, int wait1, int wait2, int rng) {
    strip.clear();
    rng = random(LED_COUNT);
    for(int a=0; a<15; a++) { 
      strip.setPixelColor(rng, color);         
      strip.show();                          
      delay(wait1);
      strip.setPixelColor(rng, (0, 0, 0));
      strip.show();
      delay(wait1);
  }
    strip.setPixelColor(rng, color);
    strip.show();
    delay(wait2);
}
void colorWipe(uint32_t color, int wait) {
  for(int i=0; i<strip.numPixels(); i++) { 
    strip.setPixelColor(i, color);         
    strip.show();                          
    delay(wait);                           
  }
}
void theaterChase(uint32_t color, int wait) {
  for(int a=0; a<10; a++) {  
    for(int b=0; b<3; b++) { 
      strip.clear();         
      
      for(int c=b; c<strip.numPixels(); c += 3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(c, color); 
      }
      strip.show();
      delay(wait);  
    }
  }
}
void rainbow(int wait) {
  for(long firstPixelHue = 0; firstPixelHue < 5*65536; firstPixelHue += 256) {
    for(int i=0; i<strip2.numPixels(); i++) { 
      int pixelHue = firstPixelHue + (i * 65536L / strip2.numPixels());
      strip2.setPixelColor(i, strip2.gamma32(strip2.ColorHSV(pixelHue)));
    }
    strip2.show(); 
    delay(wait);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should ditch every call to `delay()` in your code and learn how to use a non-blocking coding style involvingthe `millis()` function, just like in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example. That will enable you to not do busy waiting, bit do multitasking by very rapidly switching between the two tasks. There are tons of tutorials about that on the web. Please look at some of them. Then - if it isn't clear - you can always come back here. Have fun with your projekt :-)

Comment: Yep, ditch all delay(). Daisy chain 2 loops so you have 1 big loop. Write a drawing function update 2 loops at one time following global array that stores colour info of all each single LED on both loops. Setup a timer to call your drawing function every ~40ms. In main loop(), do the fancy stuff by modify the global array (screen buffer). Also check for buttons and  stuffs there in main loop. Since you separate your logic code (in main loop) and visual code (run by timer), you can do delay() in main loop.